# How to create an elbow connector from scratch programatically?

Tags: c++, shapes

An "elbow connector" in MS-Word is a 3-segment line with a control point in the middle as shown

[image: see image here]

where if I move the yellow control point sideways, then the length of the two lines on either side change accordingly while the end points remain the same. (Please ignore the "2" in the picture)

I am trying to understand how this works so that I can re-create this. Is there a "line equation" for such a line? I have some points (x,y) that are already in the shape of this elbow connector but I would like to incorporate the functionality of changing the lines on either side by controlling the control point. How would I go about re-creating this?

Comment: I posted a general answer, Please let me know if it helped! Please also consider vote/acceptance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By dissecting the lines like:

[image]

For moving the center(M) only sideways, length of lines 2 and 3 remains the same so the problem becomes how to calculate length (and direction) of the lines 1 and 4.
That can be calculated like:

```
line1_length = B.x - M.x;
line4_length = M.x - A.x;
```

For directions a comparison should first be made like:

```
if(B.x > M.x)...
.
.
.
if(M.x > A.x)...
.
.
.
```

Beginning points is already known as the position of A and the position of B. By knowing the lengths and directions of lines 1 and 4, the end points can be determined.

Good luck!

Comment: Remember that if the AM or BM angle goes under some threshold, the elbow changes to down-right-down rather than right-down-right.

Comment: @einpoklum yes you are right! But does it necessarily have to be like that? Did I understand the question wrong?

Comment: @einpoklum yes, me too.

Comment: @AKL Yes this helps a lot!

Comment: @MarcoEmerson I am glad you found the answer useful and thank you for accepting my answer. I also wish you vote the answer up too (as I did the same with your question). Simply click on the upward arrow (^) positioned on the upper left side of the answer(above the tick mark).